# Is there a way to detect which child class called a parent class method?

Tags: python, object, heap

I am working on a heap class for a course I am taking. The way they want us to set it up is to have a general heap class with methods like heapify, heappop, build_heap, etc. Then have classes MinHeap(Heap) and MaxHeap(Heap). FYI: The current Heap class is set up like a MinHeap.

My questions mostly regards to heapify and heappop. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to detect which child class called this function, or if I have to overwrite these methods in the child class.

***THIS IS A HW ASSIGNMENT***

Here is the `Heap.__init__()` method:

```
def __init__(self, array: List[int]) -> None:
        self.elements = array
        self.size = len(array) # Number of elements in heap
        self.build_heap()
```

My goal was to have some sort of check to see which child called the function and if it was MaxHeap, heapify would build a MaxHeap else it stays the same.

Comment: Let me know if I can clarify in any way

Comment: *"or if I have to overwrite these methods in the child class."* - most likely, yes. A parent should not care or know who extends it.

Comment: @luk2302 But the parent class can leave solely the comparison of two values for each child class to implement.

Comment: "I am trying to figure out if there is a way to detect which child class called this function," this is a huge red flag that your inheritance design is not correct. Your alternative approach seems much more reasonable

Comment: You could have a private class variable determining if the heap type is Min or Max. The child class will differ only in this one value.

Comment: Is *"have a general heap class with methods like heapify, heappop, build_heap, etc. Then have classes MinHeap(Heap) and MaxHeap(Heap)"* what they told you, or are you paraphrasing and leaving stuff out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent class should be ignorant of the subclass. It is better practice to call the parent constructor with an extra argument that defines how the order should be defined. This could be a comparator function, or a boolean.

Here is how you could do it with a boolean:

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self, array: List[int], maximize: bool=False) -> None:
        self.elements = array[:]  # safer to take copy
        self.size = len(array)
        self.maximize = maximize
        self.build()

    def build(self) -> None:
        for i in range(len(self.elements) // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
            self.siftdown(i, self.elements[i])

    def siftdown(self, i: int, value: int) -> None:
        child = i * 2 + 1
        while child < self.size:
            if child + 1 < self.size and self.maximize == (self.elements[child+1] > self.elements[child]):
                child += 1
            if self.maximize == (self.elements[i] > self.elements[child]):
                break
            self.elements[i] = self.elements[child]
            i, child = child, child * 2 + 1
        self.elements[i] = value

              
class MinHeap(Heap):
    def __init__(self, array: List[int]) -> None:
        super().__init__(array, False)


class MaxHeap(Heap):
    def __init__(self, array: List[int]) -> None:
        super().__init__(array, True)


# demo
arr = [3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4, 9]
minheap = MinHeap(arr)
print(minheap.elements)

maxheap = MaxHeap(arr)
print(maxheap.elements)
```

Just extend the base class with the other methods you need, and make use of the `maximize` attribute like I have done in the `build` method.

NB: I changed the name from `build_heap` to `build`, as it is already clear from the class that it is about a heap. No need to repeat that in the method name.